# Is the word "die Tüte" used in Austria?

Tags: vocabulary, austrian

I talked with some friends from Austria and they all told me that this word *"Tüte"* is really unusual in Austria.

```
die Tüte
```

I am wondering if this is true for the WHOLE of Austria, or maybe just in some parts of it, and if then it is actually a common word maybe in certain areas of Germany. Would they in Austria instead say "die Tasche" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is generally recognized as a teutonism (i.e. a word that's typically only used in Germany), at least when referring to a plastic bag or similar. Tüte is used in other contexts (for ice-cream cones, e.g.), however.

The official word would be "Tragtasche", I suppose, although the word "(Plastik)sack" and in particular the diminutive "Sackerl" are much more common.

Comment: +1 for Eistüte, wouldn't have thought of that

Answer (score 6):

Among other meanings, the word *[Tüte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tuete#Bedeutung1d)* is used as a short form of *Plastiktüte* (English: plastic bag) in colloquial German. The area of distribution is shown in a linguistic map of the linguistic atlas *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f13b/):*

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Answer (score 3):

»Tüte« hört man zwar in Österreich, aber selten von Österreichern, zumindest nicht wenn der Behälter gemeint ist, in dem man Einkäufe transportiert. Was auf fast alle Teutonismen zutrifft, gilt auch für die »Tüte«: Man kennt das Wort in Österreich, verwendet es aber nicht.

Wenn ein Österreicher etwas einkauft, gibt er die gekauften Waren nicht in eine Tüte, sondern in ein **Sackerl**. Auch wenn viele Deutsche das Wort »Sackerl« für ein Dialektwort halten, so ist es doch ein Vokabel des Österreichischen Standard-Deutsch. Man hört es von Nachrichtensprechern im Fernsehen und im Radio, und es steht in Tageszeitungen und Schulbüchern.

Mit »Sackerl« werden nicht nur Einkaufstaschen aus Papier oder Plastik bezeichnet, sondern auch jene Tüten, in denen man Lebensmittel frisch hält oder einfriert. Auch kleinere Müllbehälter sind Müll-*Sackerln*. Größere nennt man Sack (Müllsack). Müll*beutel* oder -*tüten* sind eher selten in Österreich.

Wenn man in Deutschland eine *Tüte* Eis kauft, kauft man sich in Österreich ein *Stanitzel* Eis. Jedoch setzt sich in dieser Bedeutung derzeit auch das Wort »Tüte« durch. Dieses Einsickern von Wörtern aus Deutschland ins Österreichische Deutsch geschieht durch den Einfluss deutscher Medien immer rascher. Das *Stanitzel* erleidet dasselbe Schicksal wie die berühmten *Erdäpfel* und *Paradeiser*: Es verschwindet und wird durch das in Deutschland gebräuchliche Wort ersetzt.

Beim *Sackerl* hat dieser Vorgang noch nicht begonnen.

Kleine Anekdote:
Als Kind kannte ich das Wort »Tüte« gar nicht. Als ich es das erste Mal hörte, dachte ich, damit wäre so etwas wie ein Megaphon oder eine Trompete gemeint, also etwas, das »tüt« machen kann.

Comment: Bei uns ists *eine Waffel* Eis, aber eher *Eis in der Waffel*. Aber +1 für die Trompete :D

Comment: @Jan: In Österreich ist die Waffel (Im Zusammenhang mit Eis) das flache rechteckige Süß-Gebäck, das man zu einem Becher Eis an den Tisch serviert bekommt.

Comment: Und das ist zu allem Überfluss bei uns *auch* eine Waffel. Eisessen ist lustig.

Comment: Müllsäcke haben wir natürlich auch, nur keine Säckchen. Das hier in Berlin gängige Tüte für den Einkaufsbeutel ist eigentlich auch ungenau, denn eine Tüte sollte die Form eines Kegels oder zumindest eines Zylinders haben. Sicher aber sind Tüten keine Tuten ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Was ist den nun schon wieder eine *Tute*? Ich kenne *Tüten* und *Tunten*, aber *Tuten* bisher noch nicht, jedenfalls nicht als Substantiv.

Comment: Eine Tute ist etwas, das tutet. Gerade im Kinderdeutsch ist das ein angemessener Begriff. Du lagst also nicht so weit daneben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast siehe http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%B6te

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Der Duden ist sich aber sicher, dass in manchen Gegenden Tuten doch Tüten sind: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tute

Comment: In der Tat habe ich gerade gelesen, „Tüte“ komme von „Tute“ und das vom Horn (dem, das tutet).

Comment: Ja, eine Tröte kenne ich. Die macht »tröööt«. Und eine Tüte macht »tüüüt«. Nachdem derartige Instrumente (Hörner, Hupen usw.) in Österreich aber eben »tüüüt« und nicht »tuuut« machen, gibt es eben bei uns keine Tuten. Das Verb »tuten« kommt in Österreich eigentlich nur in substantivierter Form im Spruch »hat keine Ahnung von Tuten und Blasen« vor. Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, es je in einem anderen Zusammenhang gehört zu haben (Fernsehen aus Deutschland mal ausgenommen).